# Need to remove default Wordpress Pagination

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pagination

The paginate for my site looks awful so I used Pagenavi plugin. I'm wanting to get rid of the old paginate but can't seem to figure out how. I went to the style.css file trying to delete certain lines of code.. well lets just say that didn't go too well.

How do I get rid of the pagination? It's the one on the top with no styling.

The site:  http://trextec.com/saint-augustine-fl-historic-sites/

The extension I'm using to replace the default pagination:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

PS Please don't advise me to use Firebug then magically all my problems will go away :)

Answer (score 2):

here is the working code:

Display all posts by disabling pagination:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'nopaging' => true ) );
```

Comment: Server runs out of memory. How can we disable pagination but give it a limit like last 10 posts period, no pagination?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for doing it.choose according to your ease

**FIRST** go search for this word press built-in function find it in your `index.php`,`search.php`,`page.php` etc and remove it.

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

**Second** go find this `page-link` class in your `index.php`or`page.php` and remove the whole `div`.

```
<div class="page-link">
```

Comment: I ended up using a tag in styling for the template instead. Thank you anyways. Not sure why my post has a down vote? lol           .page-link {
    display: none;
}

Comment: I think because of this line "Please don't advise me to use Firebug then magically all my problems will go away" :D anyways have a good day

Answer (score 0):

To remove the default Wordpress navigation, without touching the theme, you can override link pages arguments

```
add_filter('wp_link_pages_args', 'remove_wp_link_pages');    
function remove_wp_link_pages($args = '') {
    $args['echo'] = 0;
    return $args;
}
```

`wp_link_pages_args` permit to filter arguments, so we juste switch `$args['echo']` to `0` to disable it. The pagination will not display anymore.